# Simple jQuery in-place "balloon" notification for fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please suggest the jQuery plugin for showing the validation errors in-place, much like on MobileMe:
[image: MobileMe Validation]

What I **don't want** is fully blown validation plugin (jQuery.validation and similar).

What I do want is:

- Simple UI-only "widget"
- Small in size
- Stylable via CSS (with some defaults)
- Ideally it should be able to convert simple `span` or other tag into the balloon and show it near the field
- Of course it should provide simple API to show/hide it

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Comment: @Guntis, It's probably time for a new answer. Looks like that component isn't available anymore - I dunno. Seems strange that I would have recommended something from flowplayer at all. I think I've found a couple cool ones since then.

Answer (score 0):

[BeautyTips](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html) can get the job done.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be maintained. The last version is RC and was released  2 years ago.